# Java - get the number of active connections while using Tomcat JDBC Connection Pooling

Tags: java, jdbc-pool

In Apache DBCP there is a method getMaxActive() to get the number of active connections. I am trying to use Tomcat JDBC Connection Pooling. I am able to create a datasource and use it to run my query but I want to print to my console to see how many active connections are used in the pool.

Is there a method for this while using Tomcat JDBC Connection Pooling?